# Neesh or Nitch?

Tags: pronunciation

What is the correct way to pronounce *niche*?  I've always said and heard *nitch*, but now I hear *neesh*, but it always sounds trendy to me.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either way is correct.  "Neesh" is the French pronunciation and has always been used by some English speakers.

My preference is for "nitch" but then I pronounce clique as "click" -- I like my English English and my French French.

Comment: Haha, I like that last line.

Comment: neither "iche" or "ique" are English word endings, so if you really like your English English, use different words.

Comment: I find it interesting that it's *Americans* who tend to say ***nitch*** (as confirmed by [Collins Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/niche), which explicitly says ***Nitch*** = US, ***Neesh*** = UK). For many other words that come to mind (***filet*** and ***herbs*** in culinary contexts, for example) Americans stick with the French pronunciation where Brits go for the Anglicised version.

Comment: You need to respell it to *nitch* if that's how you pronounce it. And good luck with *cleek*. :)

Comment: Do Americans still pronounce it "nitch" when it acts as an adjective? "He operates in a niche market."

Comment: @Greybeard - I do.

Answer (score 21):

Since *niche* is a word that is directly borrowed from French, some people choose to pronounce the word using the original French pronunciation.  Merriam-Webster lists both pronunciations (as well as the halfway-between pronunciation of "nish" [nɪʃ]), so both are technically valid.

Phonologically speaking, there is nothing in the pronunciation "neesh" [niʃ] that is actually foreign to English, so to me it doesn't really sound off-putting.  A similar example would be *envelope*, which many people pronounce "onvelope", a nod to the French pronunciation (though not fully faithful anyway).

Comment: Meanwhile, the word *envelop* I've never heard pronounced the "French" way.

Comment: Meanwhile, I didn't know there was any other pronunciation than "on-velope". I've never heard "enn-velope"!

Comment: I've heard both en-velope and on-velope since I was a little kid.

Answer (score 13):

As far as I know the "nitch" pronunciation is more common in the US, whereas the "neesh" pronunciation is used more in the UK. Seems to be a tomayto-tomahto thing.

Comment: Speaking as a Brit, I had never in my life heard "nitch" until a few minutes ago, and it was spoken by an American (prompting my search and finding this question). "Neesh" is not just "used more" in the UK - it is the one and only pronunciation here.

Answer (score 2):

I grew up with Canadian French, so now when I hear *nitch*, it offends my sensitive earballs. For example, I would also never pronounce `quiche` as *kitch*!

Comment: Saving this for the “quiche, not kitch” when this comes up in conversation!

Comment: @sleighty Just try not to be a *biche* about it.

Comment: I usually keep my judgment strictly to myself :P